# Running cmd commands via .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, process, cmd

```
System.Diagnostics.Process proc0 = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
proc0.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd";
proc0.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.Combine(curpath, "snd");
proc0.StartInfo.Arguments = omgwut;
```

And now for some background...

```
string curpath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
```

omgwut is something like this:

> copy /b a.wav + b.wav + ... + y.wav + z.wav output.wav

And nothing happens at all. So obviously something's wrong. I also tried "copy" as the executable, but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Try the prefixing your arguments to cmd with `/C`**, effectively saying `cmd /C copy /b t.wav ...`

According to `cmd.exe /?` using

`/C <command>`

> Carries out the command specified by
>   string and then terminates

For your code, it might look something like

```
// .. 
proc0.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C " + omgwut;
```

**Notes:**

- A good way to test whether your command is going to work is to actually try it from a command prompt.  If you try to do `cmd.exe copy ...` you'll see that the copy doesn't occur.
- There are limits to the length of the arguments you can pass as arguments.  From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments.aspx): "The maximum string length is `2,003` characters in .NET Framework applications and `488` characters in .NET Compact Framework applications."
- You can bypass the shelling out to command by using the `System.IO` classes to open the files and manually concatenate them.

Answer (score 7):

Try this it might help you.. Its working with my code.

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo =
    new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + command);

// The following commands are needed to redirect the standard output.
// This means that it will be redirected to the Process.StandardOutput StreamReader.
procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
// Do not create the black window.
procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
// Now we create a process, assign its ProcessStartInfo and start it
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
proc.Start();
// Get the output into a string
string result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
// Display the command output.
Console.WriteLine(result);
  }
  catch (Exception objException)
  {
  // Log the exception
  }
```

Comment: You should add a `throw;` after logging the exception, unless this code is at the top level of the program. That will allow the exception to propagate to the callers.

Answer (score 1):

Daniels cmd /c idea will work.  Keep in mind there is a limit to the length of a command line probably 8k in your case see [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2003/12/10/56028.aspx) for details.

Since you are in a .Net app anyway, File.Copy may be quite a bit easier/cleaner than this approach.

Comment: He's trying to append multiple files; not sure if you can do that with File.Copy

Answer (score 1):

Even you can try this.. this is even better.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process(); 

proc.EnableRaisingEvents=false;
proc.StartInfo.FileName="iexplore";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments="http://www.microsoft.com";

proc.Start();

proc.WaitForExit();

MessageBox.Show("You have just visited " + proc.StartInfo.Arguments);
```