# C# with command line FTP help

Tags: c#, command-line, ftp, cmd, mainframe

I've been trying for a while now to set up an ftp connection with our mainframe via c#.  So far I've been able to connect and upload a file to the mainframe, which is great, but the file has the wrong record length and is set up as variable, instead of fixed record length.  After quite a bit a research I have come to the same conclusion as most people, that the ftpwebresponse function will not allow "qoute SITE" commands to be issued to the mainframe. If i'm wrong please don't hesitate to correct me, heres the code i'm using:

```
private void ftpButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string ftphost = "ftpSite";  
    string user = "myUser";  
    string pwd= "myPass";
    string ftpfileName = "test.file2";
    string inputfilePath="d:\\documents and settings\\gheff\\My Documents\\Visual Studio 2005\\Projects\\biWeeklyJob\\BiWeekly\\bin\\Debug\\file2.TXT";

    string ftpfullpath = String.Format("ftp://{0}//'{1}'", ftphost,ftpfileName);             

    try  
    {                
        FtpWebRequest ftp = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(ftpfullpath);  
        ftp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user,pwd);                 

        ftp.KeepAlive = true;  
        ftp.UseBinary = false;  //Use ascii. 

        ftp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

        FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(inputfilePath);  
        byte[] buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
        fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        fs.Close();  

        Stream ftpstream = ftp.GetRequestStream();  
        ftpstream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        ftpstream.Close();  

    }  
    catch (WebException ex)  
    {  
       String status = ((FtpWebResponse)ex.Response).StatusDescription;  
       throw new Exception(status);  
    }  
}
```

So undeterred, I tried to think of another approach, I have successfully used the command line to upload a file, change the file properties and also changed the filetype so I can send JCL jobs to the mainframe.  I am now tyring to implement this into my existing c# application, but proving harder than I thought.

I am by no means an expert in c#, but can use answers to then go and do more research to gain a better understanding.

I have seen this piece of code [C# cmd excute commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/691716/running-cmd-commands-via-net/2518365#2518365), but looking around it seems that only one command can be issued from this.

So my question is, I know it took a while to get there, is it possible to run the follow commands on the command prompt without the use of a batch file as i'm looking some feedback as the process runs?

```
open "cmd.exe"
type "ftp"
type "FTPserver"
Type "USERNAME"
type "PASSWORD"
```

Then once connection has been established

then run pre-defined commands i.e upload files, upload and run JCL jobs.
I think what i'm looking for is somthing that will write text to cmd.exe but keep the session?

I hope this makes sense.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So here is code you are asking for nevertheless I doubt that it solve your problem.

```
var cmd= new Process();

cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;

cmd.Start();

using (var stdin = cmd.StandardInput)
{
   stdin.WriteLine("ftp");
   stdin.WriteLine("FTPserver");
   stdin.WriteLine("USERNAME");
   stdin.WriteLine("PASSWORD");
} 

cmd.WaitForExit();
cmd.Close();
```

Comment: I tried implementing your code but unable to do so. Visual studio does not like var, it says it does not have a namespace? Also writeline does not work it says it can't convert system.diagnostics to system.io. Any suggestions?

Comment: @John: `var` is c# 3 keyword. Just replace first `var` with `Process` and second `var` with `StreamWriter`

Answer (score 1):

Try this cmd:

```
FTP -s:ftpcommandfilename url
```

sense the follow mode can run one command only, you can write the ftp cmd in a file and use this cmd to execute them.

```
WriteLine("FTP -s:ftpcommandfilename url");
```

By the way, I am also finding the multi-ftp-cmd-line-in-code mode, if you have got it, sharing?

Answer (score 0):

I used this [CodeProject project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/ftplib.aspx) a few years ago for a simple application that needed to send some files.  The thing that may help you is that it uses a socket to talk to the other server.  You can send raw FTP commands which should sidestep the problems you're having with the FtpWebRequest object, without having to "shell out" and use the ftp command line program.

Comment: I'll need to do a bit of research on sockets as I've never implemented them before. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Another approach you could try is to submit a jcl job to allocate the dataset with the record length, block size, et al, that your process needs.

Once that job complets, "put" your data into the dataset you just allocated correctly.  The z/OS ftp server should pick up the attributes from your existing dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a commercial FTP client that supports a COM interface and is able to send raw protocol commands?  This might not be economical if you are writing software to redistribute but if you are only trying to automate a recurring task for an internal IT project it could definately be worth it in terms of your time as a developer.  Robo-FTP might be a good choice for connecting to a mainframe because it has built in ASCII to EBCDIC translation.